# PHP ZipArchive Timeout

Tags: php, timeout, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm currently trying to find a work around to prevent a PHP script from timing out whilst creating a .zip using the ZipArchive class.

I've managed to do this no problem by overriding the max script execution time inside php.ini using set_time_limit(). However its not guaranteed that safe mode will be turned off inside php.ini on the servers that the script will be running on and I don't have access to the php.ini file. Is there any other way to stop the script timing out? Can the ZipArchive be run as a background task?

Answer (score 1):

I think time out is not problem.
It will be solved by ini_set of max_execution_time.
But memory limit is problem.
I am not facing time out issue about zip file creation of 5.8G directory. but i am faing memory limit issue.

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
This is working well in my end.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60); //60 seconds = 1 minute

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //0=NOLIMIT
```

But, there may be restrictions put in place on a shared host, so if these functions don't work as they should, ask some admin of the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve this as well, set_time_limit is no good on shared hosting in safe mode or disabled on server.

I'm using Ajax client side calls to PHP to process archiving in steps, however it opened up a few new issues.  Script timeout and some kind of "check-pointing" so I can resume on a continue operation.

So my recommendation is to use ajax/client side implementation to hit php to do work knowing the script may not finish in one call but could take N calls, and although an operation could take long enough in PHP to time out the script you can still put logic in to check for elapsed time and try to save state before a timeout and cover both cases in client for timeout/manual kick out.